# Delete first node that surround selection in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a content editablediv where user can modify text.

I use the following javascript code to insert the new text at cursor position

```
//get selection
range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);

//create new element
var ele = document.createElement("span");
ele.textContent = "myText";

//insert the element
range.deleteContents();
range.insertNode(ele);
```

This unfortunately results from

`"123<span>old text</span>456"`

to the following situation

`"123<span>old<span>myText</span>text</span>456"`

What I need to do is delete the old node around the range (`<span>old text</span>`), for example with the following pseudo-code

```
if (range.surroundNode == "#span")
     range.deleteLastNode()
```

before adding the node.

I had a look at the documentation. There is a method called replaceChild (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild) that can theoretically be used but in my div there are several span elements, all of them without id.

Any help ?

Comment: _"This unfortunately results in a situation like"_ - based on what _initial_ content? Please provide a proper [mre] of the issue, not just snippets that lack context.

Comment: Maybe you should check what the [`commonAncestorContainer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/commonAncestorContainer) of your range is? If that is not your outer div element, then you are "inside" one of the children.

Comment: *"What I need to do is delete the old node around the range"* - Are sure you want to delete the text surrounding the inserted text? The user doesn't see `<span>`s so why would the user need to replace text that's in a `<span>` of which the borders and location is unknown? If an insertion of text is just the cursor then the text should start at that point and push the text to the right. If an insertion is an actual highlighted selection of text then only the selected text should be replaced.